# Create an azure container registry Timer task with an ARM template?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-container-registry

This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-task-run-template) describes how to create an Azure Container Registry task using an ARM template.

One thing that isn't clear from the document and the reference is how to create an ACR **timer** task with an ARM template. Effectively doing this same as the [az acr task timer add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/task/timer?view=azure-cli-latest#az_acr_task_timer_add) command.

Is it possible to add a timer to an ACR task with an ARM template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, Yes. You can find the [timer trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.containerregistry/registries/tasks#TimerTrigger) in the template of the ACR task, and here is an example for the timer trigger:

```
"trigger": {
    "timerTriggers": [
        {
            "schedule": "0 21 * * *",
            "status": "Enabled",
            "name": "t1"
        }
    ]
```